# Suspicious login request when using Google id

Tags: support, login, google-openid

I am getting this error repeatedly when I try to login to the [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com) site for the first time using a Google id.

> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked
> suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Physics, please
> return to the previous page and try again.

I am using few other Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow sites,
https://stackexchange.com/users/107581/vi-su

Comment: Me too, using MyOpenId.com - on all Stack Exchange sites. I go back, resubmit and it works. This is consistent, fails first time, succeeds second time.

Comment: It seems that I get this error when I am using Google open ID and I have logged in with 2 Google accounts - I have a separate Google profile at work, so when at work I am logged with both my work and my personal profiles. SE account is associated with my personal profile, but I guess the authentication may get confused when I am logged in Google with both ones. I do not have the issue at home, where I am usually logged with **only** my personal profile

Answer (score 55):

From what I can tell, your ISP likes to assign you different IP addresses more or less by the second – and that's only slight hyperbole. As an example: between 10:02:48 and 10:05:42, a timeframe of just under three minutes, you made requests from fifteen (!) different IP addresses (most of these were heartbeat requests while writing this very question, so they all came from the same computer).

We don't usually require sticky IPs (in particular once you're logged in it shouldn't be an issue), but if during the process of logging in your IP address changes, that's extremely fishy, and that's why we bail out.

So when this happens, all I can tell you is to reload https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/login and click the Google button again, in the hope that your ISP lets you keep the same IP address for a few seconds :)

Comment: That's one screwed up ISP. o.o

Comment: Perhaps the asker is using [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)) or other anonymizing software?

Comment: @BinaryTox1n No, the IPs are all in the same /24 block.

Comment: I've had the same trouble in the last two days (thanks to a hard drive crash, I have to re-login to every SE site). But as far as I know, my IP address is (more or less) static. Could anything else be causing the message?

Comment: @mmyers Sorry to tell you, but your IP address is just as flaky. Each request from you appears to come from one random out of five different IPs.

Comment: So the solution is to try, try again? I did eventually get into chat.se today, but I'm not excited about going through this on 10 or 15 more sites.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, but only on my Android tablet using Opera.  I can log onto SO just fine on my Mac, Linux, IOS, & Windows boxes, both here at home & at work (different providers).  I've tried logging on several times in a row on the Android device (Galaxy Tab 7.7 w/ Gingerbread), but I can never get logged on.  It's more of an annoyance than a problem, but I'd be curious what I could do to be able to log on with that tablet.

Comment: Almost a year late, but maybe you recall: I assume those were IPv4 addresses? (With IPv6 I am using Privacy Addressing which implies changing IP addresses as well, though not at all as often as above. I'm not trying to hide the IP address, but want to ensure [my computer's MAC address is not in the address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64). I've not seen the problem, but I guess it might happen once in a lifetime that I'd see the same error once you use IPv6 as well.)

Comment: (Oh, forget my above question, balpha. Of course those were IPv4 addresses, as SE is not accessible over IPv6 yet. *Maybe* the IPv6 Privacy Addressing might be a rare and minor issue in the future.)

Comment: I have the same trouble, but I think it is a different case. We cannot access stackoverlow.com in China, so we have to use proxy. Most of us use google appengine as the proxy. So I think you guys have restricted access on appengine IPs. Can you guys fix this?

Comment: @davidshen84 No, it's not a different case. It's the exact same issue. Your proxy gives you different IP addresses for every request: I checked your access log for last Thursday. You made 28 authenticated requests to the site, and they came from 18 different IPs.

Comment: @balpha so how do you recommend me to resolve this issue?

Comment: @davidshen84 Either use a better proxy (at least during login), or do what I said in the answer's last paragraph.

Comment: I have this problem consistently on my iPad with any other StackExchange site other than StackOverflow. Yet it works on my Computer using the mobile network from the same iPad. Needless to say, a simple reload does not help. Any more helpful advise?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's the reason why I can't login into StackOverflow with Google Apps Engine as proxy. However, this check makes it difficult for me to login, for 1. Your sites sometimes are blocked by the mad Great Firewall of China; 2. My current ISP is strange, it not only uses different IPs for different targets, but may also changes IPs back and forth for the same target....

Comment: I've seen this Stack Exchange problem with Shaw Go, which is the Wi-Fi hotspot network of a major Canadian cable internet provider. Stack Exchange is the *only* case where I've had any unusual connectivity problems with Shaw Go. Perhaps Stack Exchange is being a bit overly cautious when watching for suspicious activity?

Answer (score 4):

This is the only thread I've read on this issue but in my experience the explanation above isn't sufficient. I've experienced it predictably during my last 3 logins. First on stackoverflow yesterday, then on programmers.stackexchange.com just now (right after login) and finally again as I logged into meta to reply to this thread. All I've done differently this week is reset chrome's history (all the way back).

Comment: Me too, using MyOpenId.com - on all Stack Exchange sites. I go back, resubmit and it works. This is consistent, fails first time, succeeds second time.

Answer (score 3):

When you got into that error page, just refresh the page on your browser. If your browser asks confirmation for resend the data, just agree with it. This works for me in firefox v26.

Don't go back and click the open ID link again, it won't work. You will get same error page.

Comment: This works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this error too, and in my case the problem is IP address which is changing rapidly.

My DSL line is low speed, so I set up a load balancer with 4 different IP addresses to load balance.

Comment: So if you use only one IP address the error goes away?

Comment: The changing IP-addresses is exactly what balpha in the acceped answer describes. How is this helpful?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, if i use one ip, there is no problem.

Comment: I have created firewall rule for stackoverflow.com; route only one dsl and then problem solved.

Comment: @rene this answer explains a possible cause for the IP change, so it is kind of helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried refreshing login page. But I was not able to login using google id. I tried this 5-6 times. Finally I went to sign up page and used google id. when you are already signed up for the site the sign up helps you to sign in. So I was able to login.