# My very mundane request was deemed suspicious, but processed anyway

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I started here:
[What is the purpose of the holes marked "Do Not Cover" on hard drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/368774/do-not-cover-this-hole)

On this computer, I was logged into the network on Meta and SO, but not yet on SU. I wanted to cast an upvote, so I clicked "Log in", which led me to the regular login page with this url:
https://superuser.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f368774%2fdo-not-cover-this-hole

I clicked facebook login (like I always do), which led to this page:
https://superuser.com/users/authenticate

It told me that my request was "suspicious" and "could not be completed". But, in spite of that message , my request apparently was processed. You can see from the freehand circle in the screenshot that it did in fact log me in (and when I went back to the original question and refreshed the page, I was now logged in).

[image]

As far as I can tell, I did nothing out of the ordinary here. Not a big deal at all, but definitely seems like a bug to me.

Comment: [Similar issue here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170875/145673)

Comment: I get that all the time when SE tries to auto-log me in when I visit a SE site, however I'm too impatient or don't realize it, and click the "Login" button before it finishes logging me in from the background

Comment: @Rachel, hmm. That's probably related, but in this case that's not exactly what happened. I spent a good 10 minutes on the original page reading the question/answers before I clicked log in. The "automatically logged in" box never popped up. But yes, it could be that I was already logged in in the background but the bug was just with the notification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

The root cause was global log in completing in the backend, but you submitting the log in form before it forced a refresh on the client side.  This looks to use like you're submitting an incorrect XSRF token, when actually you're just submitting the one we gave you before you logged in.