# Suspicious Request, but still logs me in

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

I tried to log into Meta using StackExchange ID and it says :

> **Suspicious Request**
>
> Sorry your request could not be completed because it looked
>   suspicious. [...]

But it still logged me in. Wondering if there is a bug in there.

[image]

Comment: There it says that the login fails first time. I was able to login on the first time, but still it's showing me the message - I'm wondering, if it was suspicious meta site should not allow me to login.

Comment: There are various other questions linked to that post; see the sidebar there. Anything in those that is closer to what you are seeing still?

Comment: I saw a lot of questions on Suspicious Request before posting. They all say login failed - but I was able to login and still the site said "Suspicious Request". Shouldn't this be a bug ?

Comment: Did you click the Login link? The same thing can happen when you come from another SE site, and you are automatically logged in while at the same time the Login link is still available; if the auto-login happens in the middle of the OpenID exchange the error is also displayed.

Comment: I guess that is it. I opened StackOverflow first. Couple of mins later I clicked on Meta Stack Exchange under the Stack Exchange Menu. But it didn't log me in automatically - Instead it showed me a login link. So I clicked on the login link and logged in using StackExchange ID. It logged me in and showed the message.

Comment: Right, that's the other scenario; there was one [corner case involving XSRF tokens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180716/my-very-mundane-request-was-deemed-suspicious-but-processed-anyway?lq=1) but there is another race condition there somewhere that is rare enough not to care about, I think.

Comment: Seems like it. Reply from @KevinMontrose (May 2013) says it would be fixed in next deploy.