# Unable to log in to SO account

Tags: support, bug, login, openid

I have been unable to log into my SO account for the last 3-4 days...(I had somehow managed to login 2 days back)
There has been very weird behavior:

1. There is the prompt showing that I have been logged in,
   [image: The hoverer]
   but then when I reach to a page redirected, I'm not logged in...
2. When I use the login page, and click the Google option (or use openid), my request is termed as "suspicious"... On multiple attempts, there is a request that passes thru, but then on logging in my google account, I am redirected to the SO homepage, and I'm not logged in..

Can someone help me by telling me:
What exactly is happening, and (more importantly to me) How can I log in to my account??

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Try clearing your cache and cookies, starting in some form of incongnito/private mode, and try from a different computer (if possible). In the meantime, what browser are you using?

Comment: @AnnaLear I've tried Chrome, IE, and Firefox, on windows. This one is Firefox.. (with the rest of the screen cropped...)

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Nah, no change.. Tried all those.. (private, cache, cookies, computer)...

Comment: @all (I know this doesn't work) Sorry about the delay in replying, was busy with something..

Comment: @Schoolboy I don't know if this would have any effect, but do you channel third-party traffic through your computer/network? (e.g. tor output nodes)

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi No... not thru my computer at least...

Comment: You might be changing IP address every few seconds, I saw that such thing [cause problems to login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170923/152859). Can you check it by `Start --> Run --> cmd --> ipconfig` and see if the IP really change often? (only IPv4 Address) In such case, talk with your ISP.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, that is the problem.. I'm behind an institute proxy, so, the proxy keeps using different the ISPs (we have multiple), and so my connecting IP keeps changing.. but why has this popped up so suddenly?? I've been using SO for some time now.. (Note: I've noticed this before, 4-5 times, but it passed in no more than 3-4 requests..)

Comment: It's a race condition: the IP is checked after X seconds; if by that time it is different it fails. Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Now, how do I work with it??

Comment: No idea... ask the network admin of the institute.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Great, Thanks for the help.. (Someone is very :( at the moment) I'll just keep trying again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again <0 characters left>.....