# Merge [post] into [http-post], [get] into [http-get]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently on SO there are 2 identical pairs of 2 identical tags:

- [post](/questions/tagged/post) (11,957)

> POST is one of the HTTP protocol methods;

- [http-post](/questions/tagged/http-post) (2,195)

> POST is one of the HTTP protocol methods

Please merge and synonymize `[post]` into `[http-post]`.

Same for [get](/questions/tagged/get) (4,720):

> HTTP GET is a request method

and [http-get](/questions/tagged/http-get) (456):

> GET is one of many request methods supported by the HTTP protocol.

I think `http-*` is more readable thus should be a master tag.

Comment: @michaelb958: is it a reason downvote?

Comment: On meta, duplicates are commonly downvoted. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Okay, I see. Thank for giving know. That sucks still. Why is SO and meta.SO are so different places? Just wondering.

Comment: Because we don't have a meta meta SO ;) In all seriousness, meta is a more laxed place. People can be more goofy and get away with it. See [one of my comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot#comment567949_185426)

Comment: Be sure to read [the many memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) to g3t up 2 sp33d

Comment: @abatishchev I didn't actually downvote; I just flagged.

Comment: On Meta, people also downvote because they *disagree*. Just something to keep in mind. For example, the downvoters could have been thinking what TRiG was. Still not something to take personally.

Comment: Who disagrees that sucks. Not something to take personally of course. My humble opinion. But due such disagrees there is all this tags mess on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Hold your fire!

[get](/questions/tagged/get) needs to be tidied by hand, as it currently contains [many questions about get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17825049/209139) which have nothing to do with HTTP. I know the tag wiki says otherwise, but reality is thus.

If it could somehow be locked to prevent new questions leaking in while old questions were tidied up, that would be good, but I don't think that functionality exists.

You're probably safe to go ahead with [post](/questions/tagged/post) (despite the [odd mistagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17841724/209139)).

Comment: `s/get() methods/property accessors` :-)