# What are Stack Overflow unicoins?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, unicoins

Recently I saw a widget on the Stack Overflow website which says Stack Overflow now has its own currency called "unicoins". According to this widget, a user can earn reputation, customize Stack Overflow by changing its colors and the user can also remove the vote down button from their questions and answers by spending "unicoins".

This widget does not look real, because this is out of standard of the Stack Overflow website.

Also today is 1st April. Is Stack Overflow fooling us?

[image: ss of widget]

Comment: How care you call unicorns slanderous.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day

Comment: Sorry, i have Edited now.

Comment: You can't downvote my answer! Try now!

Comment: According to my calendar, it's March 31.

Comment: @JonEricson well that does rather depend on where you are in the world. It's been April 1st in Australia for quite a while now.

Comment: @ChrisF: I have it on good authority that the Philippines also has some sort of calendar bug. It's downright unAmerican, I tell you.

Comment: SE runs on UTC.  You're about three hours too early.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This question does seek input and discussion about a salient topic in our community.  Why are you closing it and other relevant questions?

Comment: @Robert The April Fools "unicoins" prank activates based on local time, not server time.

Comment: The unicoin is a lie. (maybe that's how the cake idea was born)

Comment: Exactly @Robert. SE runs on UTC (Unicorn-Themed Currency). However, I disagree with your concern that it was three hours early. Clearly it was 5 years late (give or take three hours).

Comment: ****. I actually went "WTF WTF" for about a minute, before remembering it's already April 1st.

Comment: HOLY CRAP, this is so awesome! increased rep from 5000 to 50,000! I've been chiseling rocks all morning!

Comment: @SaqibSabir this is an april fool prank. check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227494/236035

Comment: Unicoins actually works, I sign up yesterday at meta.stackoverflow and now I have +400 reputation 7 bronze and 1 silver badge :D.

Comment: may be because you have earned `66` reps from this question..

Comment: Not being a Fool, I don't observe April Fool's day.

Comment: And they did fool me, but it was fun.

Comment: I think I'm getting CTS in my right index finger now...

Comment: This voting animation IS THE BEST!

Comment: Behold the power of x10 reputation. It make me look cool.

Comment: BTW, there is a REAL unicorn on earth:
http://news.discovery.com/animals/videos/animals-mythical-unicorn-found-in-deer-form.htm

Comment: The name "unicoin" is absolutely inspired. My congratulations to whoever came up with it.

Comment: This is 1st April prank bloody prank am sure. In fact I believe all those upvote on this question will be removed. xD

Comment: Somebody stole my Unicoins!

Comment: it would be cool if there was a page where the unicoin interface could still be accessed after apr1

Comment: They should have called dogecoins, unicoins. Not everyone likes dogs, but everyone loves a unicorn. Don't their cone horns remind you of ice cream?

Comment: "Can no longer be reproduced"? *Really?* This is not a problem!

Answer (score 294, accepted):

No. Unicoins are absolutely serious. They'll be used to buy rep in the future.

Also, any answer about unicoins is guaranteed to receive at least 16.66 upvotes within one hour and 99.99 within one day.

Comment: +1 for unicorns. They are real :-D

Comment: Wow, It's means now we can earn reputations by breaking rocks? :)

Comment: no they arent real, I increased my rep by 10, getting 1k + but only me can see it, you see my real rep which is around 150 on SO

Comment: Now I get kisses from a lovely unicorn every time I vote. Such are the powers of the unicoins!

Comment: Using Java, I created a console app that uses `Robot` class just to perform thousand clicks. I don't want to do clicking using my own mouse. Peace! :)

Comment: Almost fooled by google and stackoverflow today!

Comment: @Glenn-- The Chrome JavaScript console is more efficient, and the clicking unnecessary.  `setInterval(function() {  
 $.get("/unicoin/rock").done(function(obj) {      
  $.post(["/unicoin/mine?rock=" + obj.rock], {fkey: "YOUR_USER_KEY"});  
 }); 
}, 15000);`; also the coin drop rate seems to decrease the more you accumulate.  It's taking quite awhile to get the last 50 coins I need in order to unlock all the powers concurrently.  Perhaps the joke is that it's impossible to actually get there.

Comment: @aroth, what should I put in the "Your_User_key" ?? Also, it says "I'm a teapot"

Comment: @AmitJoki - View the page source, and search for "fkey".  You'll find some hex value like "56a478fa8260e47...".  Use that.  Or alternately, use `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` (with no quotes).

Comment: There is a [logical explanation for the teapot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot). Oh well...

Comment: For april 1st, this post is the correct answer. for other days, this is not. So BRACE YOURSELF TO GET DOWNVOTES later :P

Comment: @Mr_Green - I was about to say that nobody could possibly be _that_ pedantic.  But then I remembered that this is meta.stackoverflow. :p

Comment: 16.66 seconds since I posted an answer and I haven't got any upvote, I don't get it :(

Comment: You have got really high upvotes for such an answer. So these question and answers(ie related to unicoin) will be removed tommorrow, if it is just an april fool??? so upvotes will also removed???

Comment: Do you really believe those upvotes are a problem? This is META. Meta is not serious business. Assuming it is an april's fool, why would we remove a question clearly tagged as one afterwards?

Comment: @ThiefMaster It is (was) a very well done April joke, and yes you shall keep all the points earned for real. I actually had fun chiseling the rocks for a while. The scrolling title bar is just great.

Comment: Mandatory SPAM for those looking to get unirich faster https://plus.google.com/103638111379552295023/posts/BTizvHRKS8L

Comment: BTW, there is a REAL unicorn on earth:
http://news.discovery.com/animals/videos/animals-mythical-unicorn-found-in-deer-form.htm

Comment: Bad luck, I was unable to buy more unicoins using my piggybank. I had this error message, "We apologize, but for technical reasons we cannot currently accept payments with bacon."

Comment: @aroth thanks for the hack! I thought I would have to do all the work myself! :D

Comment: :( I bought the no downvote power up and everyone can still see and downvote my questions and answers. :( It should have at least worked throughout the day... bad, bad joke! :) Update - they are only hidden when I am logged into the site, but not for others.

Comment: @aroth http://pastebin.com/Lp8darxY

Comment: @Qix: Really? Mixing plain XHR and jQuery in the same snippet? :p

Comment: Where is my unicorn Now -_-? @ThiefMaster

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's an april fools day joke hack that I threw together in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 114):

We do have Unicoins in China :)

[image: Unicoin 100]

[image]

---

This commemorative coin, the coin of Qilin, is issued by the Chinese central bank in the year 199x. 麒麟([Qilin, or Kirin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilin)) is a Chinese mythical chimerical creature, sometimes known as the Chinese unicorn. But the creature on the coin is apparently more like a western unicorn.

Comment: That is...brilliant!

Comment: TIL China is a step ahead of us.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say that's not a 麒麟 at all. It's a western unicorn 独角兽.

Comment: They even have pi on them.

Comment: @WorldEngineer its actually pi repeating.

Answer (score 91):

Just preparing a list of what the powers actually do:

- **Guaranteed answer**: The guaranteed answer power gives you one of the following answer with the post's reputation be a constant **π**. (click on the Power for more options):

  - *Helpful:*
    You should divide the problem into smaller parts and solve each one individually. If you then combine the all the small solutions, you have solved the whole problem.

    > [image: img]
  - *Encouraging:*
    I am intrigued by your ideas and would like to subscribe to your newsletter.

    > [image: img]
  - *Inspirational:*
    much problem
    very answer
    such helpful
    many upvote
    wow
  - *Wise:*
    You are really asking the wrong question.
    What you should be asking is, “Why does it matter?”
    Once you have the answer to this bigger question, enlightenment will follow immediately.

    > [image: img]
- **Colorful comments**: Comic Sans font with cyan for normal text, pink for italicized text and red for bold text. :)

  > [image: img]
- **Bobblehead** animates avatars in 3D. They move fowards and backwards (once) like they are anchored at the bottom, when the image is loaded and you scroll down the page.
- **Access through sidebar** does what it says.
- **Voting animations**

  > [image: Dancing unicorns from mma.se]
  >
  > [image: With love ♥]
  >
  > [image: Downvote animation]
- **Top bar color chooser**: Change the colour of the top bar. Choose from one of the following options:

  - Original
  - Dark Sky - A really dark blue - rgb(17, 0, 33)
  - Dirty Doge - A really dark brown - rgb(33, 29, 21)
  - Burnt Velvet - A really dark red - rgb(28, 2, 15)
  - Black
  - Midnight Meadow - A really dark green - rgb(12, 28, 2)

Comment: Bobblehead changes the avatars when viewing a question... they only seem to do shortly after page load though

Comment: I had to spend another 10 unicoins to switch the colorful comments OFF

Comment: I wish I could read what you just said

Comment: An opportunity was missed here, there should be a unicoin shop item to set another user's text to aqua comic sans. And a more expensive item allowing you to return your text to normal. >:-)

Comment: I bought colorful comments, now I'm regretting it. Pass the eye-bleach!

Comment: Pi is wrong. Tau is the **truth**.

Comment: I just bought *colorful comments*. It's absolutely hideous and it's hard to not feel the 90s nostalgia. I love you Stack Overflow!

Comment: Now the link to the unicoin popup seems to have dissapeared, and I can't turn those horrible comment colors off again? Please God somebody help!

Comment: @adeneo, scroll [down to the page footer](http://i.imgur.com/HESp3eX.png).

Comment: Looks like the best power is to remove widget from sidebar :(

Comment: good job .. how do you capture the animations ?
you should definitlly check the DOWN-vote animations  ;)

Comment: @d.raev some examples [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/how-to-make-animated-screen-captures) :)

Comment: so how many rocks did you break?

Comment: I was really hoping a `$\pi+1$` when upvoted...

Answer (score 86):

[image]

Comment: Striking resemblance to bitcoin

Comment: Looks like [Uplay](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uplay_logo.jpg).

Comment: @Wold actually that's from bitcoin project indeed. Thought it's obvious!

Comment: Looks like a modern day Nazi symbol to me.

Comment: @Fernando68 Funny!

Answer (score 58):

Here there's an autominer

```
(function uniMine()
{
    $.getJSON('/unicoin/rock', function(data)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $.post('/unicoin/mine?rock=' + data.rock, {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey});
        }, 10000);
    });
    setTimeout(uniMine, 11000);
})();
```

Comment: Ew, passing a string to `setTimeout`... `setTimeout(UniMine,11000)`, please!

Comment: @Niet I can't stand it either O_o IN THIS POST USING MY POWARZ

Comment: I wrote my own autominer in PHP, much better UI in a "real" console window XD [Awesomeness](http://prntscr.com/35xqbi)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that was too mainstream?

Comment: This code appears to be taken from @aroth's comment: meta.stackoverflow.com/q/227311

Comment: Isn't there any script for reputation mining?

Comment: It's fun, but also sad, to see that someone (many, I suppose) already wrote the same code as yourself.

Comment: And here is some code to place it in the top bar: `$(".icon-help.js-help-button").html('<img border="0" src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOOzs.png" onclick="$(\'#uc-sidebar-module\').click();" width="25" height="25" style="position: relative; top: -6px;">');`

And you can use this to hide the sidebar module: `$("#uc-sidebar-module").css("display", "none");`

Compiling it in a simple Greasemonkey script makes it stay :)

Answer (score 45):

Stack Exchange, Inc, has released a new digital fiat currency for today's information warrior:

## Unicoin ₰

Jeff and Joel set out to make an "information exchange", where knowledge experts could openly trade information, because they knew that one day information would be of such inestimable value that by mining it from the world's experts, they would become Unicornaires. This was their lofty dream.

Unfortunately society has yet to recognize the treasure trove held securely at Stack Exchange, Inc, and most of their attempts to leverage this vast wealth have fallen flat.  Sure, minor things have picked up a few million US dollars here and there, but nothing to compare with the actual, real ultimate power of the information they've diligently mined over the years.

Joel, being somewhat more aggressive a businessman, intended to start off with a fiat currency, but it made Jeff feel funny inside, so they delayed, and delayed, and delayed.  Eventually, between this and other disagreements, they parted ways amicably.

However, in the meantime, fiat digital currencies changed significantly and exploded.  Joel knew he was on the right track, but needed time to ensure that the exchange would operate properly.  He intended to release it January 1st, along with the new Meta.SE, but there were rumblings in the digital currency community that a major exchange had serious flaws, and so the decision was to knuckle down and make sure everything was ironed out so this new currency wouldn't suffer the problems of its forebears, and also to distance itself from the impending implosion so as not to be associated with the bad parts of digital currency.

Having done that, as of April 1st, 2014, Stack Exchange Inc is pleased to release Unicoin.

#### It is universal.

#### It, like information, is timeless.

#### It is both mythical and magical.

Enjoy your unicoins!

Comment: Delayed? 6-8 years? Jeff quit his job in early 2008 and the first podcast was in April 2008.

Comment: Unicoins already exist: http://unicoin.info

Comment: With the emphasis on *today's* ;)

Comment: It's actually Stack Exchange, __Inc__. Not _LLC_. We don't want someone to come along and read information which isn't true.

Comment: Not being a Fool, I don't observe April Fool's day.

Answer (score 22):

Unicoins are useless and may become illegal as bitcoins. Do you want to go in jail? Give me yours now and you'll avoid problems.

My unicoin account is @4pr1lf00l.

Thanks.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. This is all nepotism if you ask me, and unethical at a time when information should be freely shared and accessible to everyone and every common person or "noob". Yeah, I am one, so there. But seriously, this will create a separate class where your average developer has to "buy" their way into the internet to find information. I am totally against any form of capitalist digital currency that only serves to bolster egos and balloon reputations that have not really been earnt.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Actually Unicoins is real deal, and users should go for it... I've scored above 3K Unicoins and what I get on my profile page is the unicoin count *(only visible to the user)*...

[image: 3K Unicoins]

[image]

I am also able to redeem these coins at certain places, also you get extra options like..

- **Unigun** (Earn double the reputation on each upvote)
- **Stealth Mode** (No one can downvote your NEW answers for the first 15 minutes)
- **Shower Me Reputation** (Earn Reputation On Minor Edits)
- **No Barrier** (Take out 200 Reputation cap for a day)

I had Around 52.5K in the morning and I just used No Barrier and did various edits and now my reputation is 53.2K so this is really fun..

Note that the reputation earned from unicoins is hidden from the users profile. You cannot really see the user is earning reputation out of what.. He may earn from edits, he may earn double from upvotes..

Thanks Stackoverflow for such a wonderful integration to the website.

> Happy April Fools Day, these unicoins will be out in 24 hour's, it's just an April Fools Day prank, Stackoverflow did do some mistakes such as 
>  - Unicoins show different count on each Stack Exchange Website
> - They don't show up on your profile page *(They would certainly show as it will be counted as a major integration)*
> - Everythings on jQuery, Stack is not that loose to provide coins which can be easily manipulated.

Comment: -1 not enough jquery... just kidding

Answer (score 17):

In all seriousness, besides the obvious April Fools celebration, I actually think it's a clever way of knowing who's using an AdBlocker.  The initial hook is where an ad normally loads.  I'd be surprised if there wasn't some metric being gathered about what percentage of active users access the Unicoins app and thus are bypassing ad revenue.

Pretty clever. :)

[image: ad]

Comment: But most logged-in users don't see the adds correct?

Comment: @NoBugs I did when I switched to Internet Explorer from Chrome (where I do have an ad blocker installed).  Pretty sure I was logged in to both.

Comment: Please tell me you don't actually believe this.

Comment: @balpha Do you get paid?  Money has to come from somewhere.  Maybe you're benevolent overlords who don't care about the financial side of things, but if I ran a business, I would do it.  Information like this is useful for knowing how effective your revenue-generating techniques are. So, yes, I do believe it's a real possibility, and I even think it would be the *smart* thing to do by people on the financial side of your company.

Comment: In thinking more about it, though, I suppose there might be an easier way of determining this, just by cross-referencing the number of page hits per day with the amount of ad revenue generated per day.  I'm not sure how much information things like Google AdSense report or deliver to their clients.

Comment: If we want to know whether a user runs an ad blocker or not, there are much easier ways to do that: Just have JavaScript in the ad that confirms it was loaded. Believe it or not, this thing was just for fun. Also, the Unicoin widget wasn't in an ad spot. It was all the way at the top. And it was for logged in users only, and anonymous users are the ones who see most ads. That's why the question "is user X running an ad blocker" probably isn't even interestion. Overall percentages -- sure.

Comment: @balpha Interesting.  When I logged in with IE, I definitely didn't see the Unicoins image.  Can't retest it now, anyway.  And there's no need to be offended.  I did say that the majority of the intent and purpose was "April Fools celebration".  It wasn't a criticism of you.  Thanks for the work you put in to give everyone a bit of a laugh.

Comment: You forgot to review 5 suggested edits! Just saying...

Answer (score 16):

I am currently counterfeiting Unicoin via userscript. Of course, the Unicoin is as shiny and as real as any other Unicoin obtained via mining...

---

After leaving the script running for 5-6 hours, the gain is diminishing as @Mark Henderson mentioned in the comment. Only 1 successful mine per 20+ mines, i.e. 1 successful mine per 3-4 minutes. I managed 687 Unicoins on StackOverflow, though (and I used most of it to by power-ups).

---

The rate of mining restored after I stop mining for about 2 hours, either that or because I used up most to buy all the power-ups.

Comment: Keep us posted on how that's working out for you :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: It is already working, although there are some 409 errors that I'm currently trying to fix.

Comment: @Sklivvz works for me... You need to get the intervals just right, that's all

Comment: It seems to scale the number of coins received per mine. After I mined around 200 coins, I'm now only getting a hit of 1 coin for maybe 10-20 mines.

Answer (score 15):

Free unicoins to everyone!

```
var exploit = {
    lastTime : 0,
    totalNum: 0
};

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    var a = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    var id = a.rock;
    var sender = settings.url;

    if (sender.indexOf("icoin/rock?") !== -1){
        var currentTime = parseInt( new Date().getTime() / 1000 );
        if (currentTime - exploit.lastTime > 11){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + id,
                data: {'fkey': StackExchange.options.user.fkey}
            });
            exploit.lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    } else {
        var res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
        exploit.totalNum += res.value;
    }
});
```

Just open unicoin miner, paste this in the console and wait. You can see your progress by typing `exploit.totalNum`

Comment: If you like my script - please feel free to upvote my answers on SO :-). At least I will get some more real points out of the April fool's day.

Comment: And upvote your avatar too with my magical unicoin powers.

Comment: "Paste this in console" means what ?

Comment: @Shrivallabh If you don't know what he/she/it means, then you are not worthy to be here not use that code. Sorry. Do not pass GO and do not collection $200.

Comment: OK i thought this forum is to help people on understanding the concepts they don't know,my bad.

Comment: @Shrivallabh https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: @Shrivallabh, actually, this one (meta) is to talk about that, not really help people programming. Anyway, just follow Bor691's link to know how it works (if you use Chrome).

Comment: +1 sufficient jquery

Answer (score 12):

### APRILFOOL

Yes They are making us **FOOL**. After buying a power `Reputation to the max
Increase your own reputation by a settable factor.` I have taken this two screen shots from my and my friends computer

**From my account [65k reputations]**

[image]

**And from my friends computer [6.5k reputations]**

[image]

Comment: Typical client-side hack lol

Comment: lolololololololo

Answer (score 10):

Its an April fools joke combined with a very clever way of make us click on various points in the site..
one can only imagine the benefits of that..

Comment: This answer is obviously wrong and misleading and should be deleted. Somebody wants all the coins for himself!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This answer is not misleading and 101% correct. and shouldn't be deleted..

Answer (score 7):

No! It's real deal!

Have a look at my unlocked ***Voting animations***:

[image: Voting animations]

Full animations sprites: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XY5D.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjvfW.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMyYU.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q8j8.png)

---

**EDIT:**

Watch this animations at:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/3gT6W/)

Answer (score 6):

I honestly wish that Unicoin is only a joke. I strongly feel it as well. However, if it's true, it's SE's way of saying goodbye to the world.

The stack is what it is today because of all the valuable knowledge, professional user experiences and quality moderation. With Unicoins, it will be a matter of BUYING your way to the top rather than EARNING it. And not to forget abasing and abusing your rights.

I've never heard of 'dividing someone's rep by 10!'. What were they thinking??!!

So, it's got all the WRONG ingredients to make it a joke, or a bad idea. I don't believe this is true.

Having said, that, I think the mining game will do good as a 'cooling off' mechanism even without the coins. Probably a good game for FB or some other social network. Then again, it's just JavaScript - too easy to break.

No, it's not real!

Comment: A serious answer to an April fool, simply brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

You lost The Game.

P.s. Don't let [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) near this.

[image]

Comment: [I already won it years ago](http://xkcd.com/391/)

Answer (score 5):

this is to check [thefmaster's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227364/222701) that:

```
any answer about unicoins is guaranteed to receive at least 16.66 upvotes 
within one hour and 99.99 within one day.
```

so this is an answer about unicoin and i must get **16** upvotes in 1 hour. Right??

#### UPDATE

Ok here is my answer about unicoin.[How to mine unicoin automatically on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227562/222701)?

Comment: No, this is an answer about answers about unicoins; the same rules do not apply

Answer (score 2):

If you manage to get 1000 unicoins within 24 hours period, you will receive moderator flag automatically for one month. Do not waste this unique opportunity which will not repeat. The elections are gone, an auction will occur in the next period.

Answer (score 2):

Damn it! I have spent 65 unicoins but my posts don't have the purple shadow. I think the functionality is broken :D

**Edit:** Ok, I see it now, it works just in meta. Has somebody managed to buy more unicorns? Mining them is too slow :D

Comment: You are a programmer buddy, Just make an auto clicker bot and earn unicoins.

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm here just by mistake :D

Answer (score 2):

I took me 1 minute to figure it was a joke, at first I thought it was like hats, and what made me figure out was:

> 80 Unicoins - disable down vote for **all** you answers and questions.

Dirt cheap, too cheap, that couldn't be, at that moment I knew it is 1<sup>st</sup> of April.

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent hours mining enough Unicoins to make the comments show nice colours - only to find that the comments are still the same boring black in Meta!

Disappointed!! Bah!

Answer (score 2):

NO! You're wrong! YOU LIAR!
Unicoins are real! Do you hear me? UNICOINS ARE REAAAAAL!!!
Peter told me so! He also told me that they come from Neverl... hey wait.....

Answer (score 1):

The question is "What are Unicoins?".

Unicoins are an inherent cheapening effect which makes users disoriented and confused about what parts of the site are real.  You "cause" things to happen which are only illusions to the user, and there is no "directions" or explanation.

If I had the option to remove this gag I would do so.  Stack Exchange is a serious site and to litter it with such useless stuff may be fun to most, but is rather unprofessional.

It reminds me of the "Cookie Clicker" game - which was a pointless time-wasting game and nothing more - but at least the game was its own entity and not a downplay of a real thing.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, there is a REAL unicorn on earth:
http://news.discovery.com/animals/videos/animals-mythical-unicorn-found-in-deer-form.htm

Comment: Oh, deer... :-)

Comment: ! XD            ..................

Answer (score 1):

Well of course it's serious. I also just discovered that the word gullible isn't actually in the dictionary!

Comment: Why would someone write a word on your ceiling that isn't even in the dictionary?

Comment: Exactly! And why was he on my ceiling! I need more peanut butter, but my Uncle's toe hurts.

Answer (score 1):

#### BEWARE

**T̖̟̲̼̟͙̝͗o̲̗̜̹ͮͭ͋**n̹͊͗̋̓̃͡y͈̻̙̣̻͎ͧ̒̅ͯ̂ ̷̀t̵͕̝̮̲̓̿̆̾͊h͕̜e͙̟͈͚͈̳̿͋ͮ̂͠ ̙͙̎̒U͖͕̗͚n̪̹̗̮͖̣̎ͩ̀̉̈̐̚ͅ**i̸̝̤͉͍̋̚c̖̫̅ͨ̀̀ͯ̂͘ȍͭ̓͂̎͐͏̗̻̩̹̤̫r̢͉̘͓̗͓̟͈̓̒ͩ̅̏͑n͚** ͎͇̫̮̺̹ͭ̑͗̇̽i̧͖͕̠͆ͫs̒̂͝ ̲̗͖̣̑ͤ̔́̓͗c̚̚͠o̺̬̞̳̫͊̈́͋ͣm͚͇̑̈́ͭͪ͌́i̪͔**n͇̰̙̳̣̰̳̽͋̚͡g̰̹̰ͫ̄̾͘.̵͈̟̪̮̝̥ͫ̆ͩͩ.̛͖̬͌ͯͪͯͦ̈̋ͅ.̶̬̘̲ͮ͂ͥ̋ͣ̏**

## It's happening [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/442351)!

I can feel him touching me...  SAVE ME.

Comment: Did you mean "SAVE the world?"

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question. Unicoins are the method of currency in the evil alternate universe, where the good guys have goatees. Obviously the appearance of the unicoins in StackOverflow means a rift in space and time is currently occuring. I just saw my mom without a goatee walking around with a 3 barrel shotgun... a 3 barrel shotgun! obviously my alternate universe evil mom.

Luckily in the alternate universe they don't have good QA as I tried buying a tag with bacon and it wouldn't let me.  We're safe, for now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the moderators will not get away with this by just saying it was a joke. If it were, they have been lying. It is offending. I don't understand what is funny about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it and I love the rainbow and happy colors!

+! for Unicoins!

The only thing I'm missing are the unicorns flying all over!

Comment: BTW, there is a REAL unicorn on earth:
http://news.discovery.com/animals/videos/animals-mythical-unicorn-found-in-deer-form.htm

Answer (score 0):

These unicorns are so cool. I love april's fools :)

Answer (score 0):

Dammit! Missed a big opportunity here...

Always tried to increase my "reputation" via some not-really-decent answer, maybe even reading something regarding the specific question. I suffered the tunneling effect, so this morning, when I saw all these great **unicorns** all around I didn't thought "come on man, just submit a random question, so you will get a lot of upvotes for no apparent reason".. now is to late. At least I will try with this useless, but still very heartfelt, comment/answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess no one else tried to **buy** unicons so I give you a hint .. you can trade them for alternative valuables like **bacon** :)

Comment: I have a bacon t-shirt with each letter an element from the periodic table! Chemistry is awesome! B Ac O N

Answer (score 0):

Unicoins are better than those Stale Oracle Java Dukecoins

Answer (score 0):

April Fools! XD

If it isn't obvious from almost all the information in the widget, you can look at the small "fine print" at the bottom:

> Availability may be limited based on factors. Prohibited where void.
>   Stack Exchange Inc. does not endorse or encourage behaviors that
>   should not be endorsed or encouraged. Not legal tender except in
>   localities with citizenship rights for unicorns. Stack Exchange Inc.
>   reserves the right to amend, cancel, or continue this promotion for
>   any reason, including, but not limited to, any reason that would
>   interfere with the invariance, continuation, or non-existence thereof.

Answer (score -1):

Any coin based in a non-mythical animal (as all we know a unicorn it is for sure) must be real, like the one based in those wild bits inside our devices (computer like).