# Super Unicoin Miner

Tags: discussion, unicoins

[image]

As Stack Overflow has introduced Unicoins as their preferred currency I felt it was important as a self-respecting coder to automate a way to mine them!

And here is the result:

[Super Unicoin Miner!](https://github.com/matthew-ch-robbins/Super-Unicoin-Minetastic)

To use the Super Unicoin Miner...

1. Clone/Fork etc repo!
2. Build in Visual Studio!
3. Run and focus the Super Unicoin Miner. While miner is focused move your mouse cursor over the browser window and press enter. Behold infinite clicking capabilities!

**I had a blast building this but I want to know... Does anyone else have a better way?**

PS: My April Fools joke is that it won't stop clicking. Have fun :)

Comment: How long will it take before I can buy a Tesla?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227404/186964

Comment: Ha, that kicks the hell out of mine. Damn web developers. :)

Comment: @nhahtdh - Yep, though technically [mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227311/you-have-75-unicoins#comment744975_227311) was first.  Helps being in Australia.

Comment: Curse you aroth! I'm in Australia too! You and your web-dev witchcraft.

Answer (score 15):

You do not need C# here.

Here is my code

```
var exploit = {
    lastTime : 0,
    totalNum: 0
};

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    var a = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    var id = a.rock;
    var sender = settings.url;

    if (sender.indexOf("icoin/rock?") !== -1){
        var currentTime = parseInt( new Date().getTime() / 1000 );
        if (currentTime - exploit.lastTime > 11){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + id,
                data: {'fkey': StackExchange.options.user.fkey}
            });
            exploit.lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    } else {
        var res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
        exploit.totalNum += res.value;
    }
});
```

Just open unicoin miner, paste this in the console and wait. You can see your progress by typing `exploit.totalNum`

Comment: I just mined 100+ unicoins by this and bought the power of voting animation and first upvoted you!

Comment: But I haven't earned that power on SO. :P

Comment: This is faster than http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227404/188498 because it mines immediately once a rock becomes available. The downside is that you have to keep the Unicoin miner open.

Comment: I posted this in my console with unicorn miner opened and it did not work :( Nothing happened.

Comment: @Dgrin91: It can take a minute for the `exploit.totalNum` to change. Wait a bit then check it again.

Comment: Where do you get the miner from?