# Installation of mining rigs and rock freezers

Tags: feature-request, unicorns

As it appears the rocks are susceptible to going off in a relatively short time I would like to propose a syndicate where cooling is provided and mining rigs installed to allow the more efficient (and better RSI protected) mining of currency.

Is this possible on the site currently?

Comment: This question was asked in regards to the 2014 April Fools feature, ["Unicoins"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins). Since it is no longer April 1st, Unicoins are now considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably be declined because the grass needs that green Jello to grow.

Without this Jello, Unicorntopia would be a barren wasteland. It is only through the blessings of the Unicorn Gods that we can receive coinage from these mysterious rocks- we shall take what we can get.

Comment: Did you decide to answer to *every* question related to unicoins? :-)

Comment: Um, yes! I'm the inventor of unicoins- you can see proof in the about section [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229501/blue-ice).

Comment: Thats a solid proof you got there. You should also thanks these questions for [this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1938279#1938279)