# How do I know my Unicoins are safe?

Tags: support, unicoins

Let's face it, you can spend thousands of dollars on your [mining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227404/150214) rig, and store up a vast wealth of Unicoins, but things can still go very  [wrong](https://www.mtgox.com/) if there's a problem with security.

Can I have reassurance that my Unicoins are being stored [securely](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702303546204579437462303753346)?

Answer (score 4):

Buy a Unicorn (With unicoins ofcourse)
Or catch a unicorn in the secret rainbow valleys.

They're easy to find, but the location isn't.

Here's a map to the secret valley:

[image: rainbow valley]

Answer (score 0):

Unicoins, the main currency of Unicorntopia, are regulated by the UMF (Unicorntopia Monetary Fund). The special unicorn seal on the unicoin tells you that it is safe and secure.

If you have any doubts, then you can bite a unicoin to make sure it is real. Do you taste that gold? Good.

Comment: I tried to bite it, but all I got was a mouthful of glass, plastic, and electrical components. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @fredley Go for the RAM. The gold interconnects work a bit better to fuel your imagination.

Comment: @fredley you're not biting hard enough

Comment: If you go for the ram, it tastes like meat!?

Comment: @Sklivvz unicorn != unicoin