# Reputation Farm Capacity

Tags: support, reputation, fun, gaming-the-system

How much rep could a rep farm farm if a rep farm could farm rep?

Comment: Well OBVIOUSLY I would get DV to oblivion! No fun tag :P

Comment: But how much fun could the fun tag tag if the fun tag could tag fun?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - evidently  `-8` (and dropping)

Comment: -7 and counting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a topic that is off, how much off can an off-topic topic be off, if an off-topic topic could off topic? *That doesn't even make sense*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rep farm would farm as much rep as they could farm *if* a rep farm could farm rep.

Answer (score 4):

Because rainbow bacon stripes:

[image: bacon!]

Comment: Did you kill a unicorn to make colored bacon!!!

Comment: No, as seen in my other answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227561/189160 you can see that I know where the rainbow valley is located. I just got that from a Unicorn.

Comment: Remember not to eat the food when you get there they wont let you leave.

Comment: That's why I brought it here :)