# How to effective mine more Unicoins by hammering rocks?

Tags: discussion, javascript, april-fools, unicoins

I've clicked the hell out of this Unicorn-app and almost destroyed my mouse - got some suggestions on how to be more effective mining Unicoins?

I mean, there must be some javascript-hack?

> Placed Bounty: 100,000,000 reputation points

---

Edit: Thanks to everyone having some little fun at this harsh and unemotional website. :) A big shout-out to the SO-Devs for this awesome widget. cya

Comment: You should outsource the clicking off-shore. That would certainly be cheaper than the unicoins you gain, so that's a clear win-win.

Comment: nailed it wesley :)

Comment: I have a python script to automate mining ;)

Comment: pics or it did not happen (dpaste is allowed also) :D

Comment: I love unicorns!

Comment: I have the code. Need this question reopened! Unfortunately, the code is in C#...

Comment: @Dialecticus  I have the code, or at least the outline of the code, notated in the margin of my book.  There isn't room for the full publication yet but I'll do so soon.... aaacck! help!  heart attack!

Comment: looks like it's open again...

Comment: @init3 I hope your question wont be deleted like mine similar did. There are clandestine forces at work that want you to break the mouse while mining Unicoins...

Comment: hehe - it's more that nerdy "uhhh, that's so offtopic *downvote hammer*" thing over here ;)  // edit: Zdravo ;)

Comment: Mined a rock.  Instead of containing Unicoins, contained bobcat.  Would not mine again.  Will send army of raptormolpys to do mining.

Comment: *Placed Bounty: 100,000,000 reputation points*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Keith's C# class [`MouseOperation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/395718) and the code below all you need is to point to the rock and hold Shift:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vkey);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0xA0 /*VK_SHIFT*/) == 0)
            continue;

        MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);
        MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Countdown to SO implementing a `Dead Time Interrupt`  for incoming mouse clicks.... 5... 4... 3...

Comment: marked correct because c#

Answer (score 5):

```
var o = new Collection(StackExchange.Account.Derek, StackExchange.Account.init3);

o.addToCollection(StackExchange.Account.Wesley);   // update: forgot this!
o.transferTo(StackExchange.Account.Cryptoburner);  // notice the notation
```

Works for me! :-o

Comment: ^^ DOSNT WORK.....................

Comment: PLS ITS URGANET

Comment: @WesleyMurch bugger! I forgot the last part. I'll update.

Comment: TNAK YOU IT SOLVE MY PROBEM

Comment: -1 NOT Enoguh jQuery!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 every downvote is actually a transaction from the downvoters account

Comment: HOW TO GIVE BOUTNY FOR THIS QUERY???????????

Comment: You need to donate bacon to me so I'm in the mood to enable the bounty-snickers-feature!

Answer (score 3):

```
StackExchange.uc.setBalance(99999999);
```

Unicorn ftw

Comment: that didn't work except that it was shown literally, but not usable

Comment: @AmitJoki - Hmm you are right, I'll work on it more.

Comment: +! I HAD TH ADME SAME PROB<EM

Comment: Won't work:  Unicoin Integer Overflow at 99999998  :-(

Comment: Is that what a uint is???

Comment: This only changes the count of Unicoins on the client-side, not on the server-side. After a refresh, it's undone.

Comment: Fits with the theme of April Fools though...

Answer (score 3):

The script here does the job better :), from: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227404/171291

```
(function uniMine()
{
    $.getJSON('/unicoin/rock', function(data)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $.post('/unicoin/mine?rock=' + data.rock, {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey});
        }, 10000);
    });
    setTimeout(uniMine, 11000);
})();
```

Comment: I did pretty much the same thing before coming here to post my script. Instead of explicitly requesting a rock, I was just subscribed to `$.ajaxSuccess` and sent the mine request when the rock was received. Yours looks like it might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url.indexOf('/unicoin/rock') !== -1) {
        var rock = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).rock;

        $.post('http://stackoverflow.com/unicoin/mine?rock=' + rock, { fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey });
    }
});
```

Pretty much the same thing as stringo0, only this one listens for rocks, and immediately sends a mine request.