# Unicoin mining actually make my CPU go 100%

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unicoins

Is StackOverflow actually doing something besides showing the small [unicoin mining game](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins) on top? Because I got my CPU going up to 100% use by simply... clicking rocks. It really doesn't seem like a game that would take the full processor, however when I run it, `top` consistently shows firefox consuming all resources.

So, is the mini-game actually doing something else on the back? Wouldn't it be really cool if we were actually mining, say, bitcoin for SO in a distributed manner while *playing a game about mining crypto currency*? If it's not being done I propose that in the future it should be done, maybe next year (;

Comment: It's a conspiracy, that's what it is.  If you can solve it, you win the game.

Comment: Wild speculation: the frame rate might be unlimited, if so it redraws as quickly as it can even if that means 100s of frames per second </probably not true>.

Comment: It appears that Firefox is not a unicoin compliant browser. I tried IE and Chrome and CPU usage is fine there. I assume both are unicoin compliant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to imply that those aren't real rocks you're mining. They are, but there are several layers of abstraction between you and them. When you click the GUI rock, the server relays that to a small robot controller. It dispatches commands to any of an army of mining bots, each equipped with a small pickaxe.

The robots harvest unicoins for SE, they pay you a portion for your work.

**It's all real.**

---

<sup>This doesn't explain the CPU load, but I had to clear that up. It probably just needs more jQuery.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Note that it actually says nothing about Unicoins in the actual interface

[image]

What really happens is that you are working on generating an SHA-256 hash in order to pair it with previous hashes. Every user on Stack Exchange is doing this simultaneously in order to maintain the accuracy of the coin mining. You were not told this because it was implied by the naming convention in the link.