# "Participate in Meta" should be deleted in Help Center > Privileges

Tags: feature-request, meta, privileges, help-center

1. [Help Center > Privileges > Participate In Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) doesn't seem to be necessary because Meta SE doesn't have its own Meta.
2. According to [Help Center > Privileges > Comment Everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), the privilege to post a comment is set at 5 reputation. It seems to be far lower than other sites which require 50 reputation points and [Vote Down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is set at 100 reputaiton. Are they intentional?

Comment: 2 is intentional I think. There was some drama before about people that were very active on SO not being able to downvote SO-related proposals here because of the rep barrier. There should be a dupe or something about one too.

Comment: @M.A.R. I see. I don't see any problem with them at all. Thanks.

Comment: Vote down at 100 is new as of [yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286150/307988)

Comment: @Cai Wow, ..... Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the link. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. The reason why MSE Help Center can't get rid of that particular privilege is it will affect other sites. Then, how about "comment everywhere" and "downvote"? Will they be implemented across SE?

Comment: @Rathony no, they are specific to MSE. Commenting here was always set to 5, from the beginning of Meta as far as I know. Downvoting at 100 is also special case here only, think the question linked by Cai explains the reasoning. Anyway, neither are likely to be copied to any other site.

Comment: @Rathony I think the privilege page *content* is there so it can sync across the network not the actual rep level (or at least the rep level is overridden here. The rep levels are already different on beta vs graduated so it makes sense that there are different levels)

Comment: @Cai Then, I think there should be no problem in reducing the rep points to 1 from 5 so that there would be less confusion.