# Change the word delete to hidden

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, wording, deleted-posts

Having your post deleted is very demoralizing. You likely don't feel like participating in it again when it happens. It's also intuitively considered permanent.

"Deletes" on SE are soft, meaning the post is just hidden from public view.

With this in mind, why not call deletion "hidden"? It would be less insulting or demoralizing and is intuitively undoable. I think catching those new users that post poorly at first but get better would increase if "deleted posts" were called "hidden posts" instead. They'd be more likely to repair their bad posts and learn how to contribute within site guidelines.

Comment: "Having your post deleted is very demoralizing." I appreciate that it often probably *is*, but it shouldn't *have to be*, if the appropriate 'people skills' are used by all parties concerned.

Comment: @topomorto Typically, you just discover it's been deleted while you were out. Or worse, while you were editing. Sometimes there's comments, sometimes not.

Comment: @fredsbend apart from obvious cases (e.g. spam, offensive material, [this kind of thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308865/how-to-know-if-my-cat-get-broken-hand),), I'd suggest that deleting a *new* user's question without a friendly comment that does a good job of explaining why is usually poor moderation. If it's a more experienced user who should already know - then they should already know, I guess!

Comment: It's "hidden from view" for 100% of occasional (aka anonymous) visitors, and for over 99% of registered users who don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts. They don't need to be confused because tiny fraction of the users can see it.

Answer (score 13):

Someone saying "hidden" makes me think of posts scoring -3 or lower, which are faded to make them harder to read - or of spoiler markup. Both things that hovering clears up.

Additionally, "hidden" implies that anyone can find them if they know how to, which isn't true - only moderators, users with the moderator tools privilege, and the author of the post can see them. With the exception of these users, the post *is* deleted. Even low-reputation users will have difficulty finding their post again as it won't be listed on their main lists of questions or answers.

Also, I think that calling it a "soft delete" really isn't necessary... even in computer systems, deleted files can often be easily recovered provided they haven't been overwritten (and sometimes even then). [Several](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/delete) dictionary [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delete) include mentioning that "deleted" implies simply "drawing a line through" text. This is an action that can certainly be recovered from.

I appreciate your concern and I can understand wanting to find better vernacular for this but I sort of wonder if it gets into a similar amount of hand-wavey-ness like the difference between "profile" and "account" (which are technically different from each other).

I don't think that calling these posts "hidden" instead of "deleted" is accurate, nor do I think that it's likely the term will be adopted widely... it might be used by the system, but getting the users to change what they say, particularly long-time users, would be difficult, particularly if they don't like the term, as for the reasons mentioned above.

There may be another word that could work but I don't think "hidden" is it.

Comment: Half of your argument is "because *status quo*". That's not particularly valid.

Comment: Suggestion for other word: *Supercalifragilistic*? I foresee large adoption ...

Comment: @fredsbend Literally _none_ of this answer says "because status quo..."  There are 5 paragraphs pointing out 3 problems with changing to your suggested term, and a 2 paragraph conclusion saying that because of these problems, there's no apparent advantage to making the change.

Comment: @Ward What is this supposed to mean then: *"gets into a similar amount of hand-wavey-ness like the difference between "on hold" and "closed""* followed by *"very few experienced users say "your post is on hold"... even when it is"* and *"nor do I think that it's likely the term will be adopted widely"* and finally *"it might be used by the system, but getting the users to change what they say, particularly long-time users, would be difficult"*. This is lifted from 3 of the 6 main paragraphs. In case you're having trouble with the *literal* meaning of half `3 / 6 = 0.5`.

Comment: @fredsbend no, half of this argument is something like "because most people find the status quo acceptable", and that's a perfectly valid argument against change.

Comment: @muru No, that's not a valid argument. It's not even an argument. It's just a sign post for others to vote "no, we want status quo". If you need MSE rep, such an answer is perfect ([I've gamed the system, so no judgement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273127/212646)). If you want to forward a real argument, not so much (which is truly what forwards a real discussion).

Comment: @fredsbend I'm sorry, but I don't see why an argument has to forward the discussion. If you like to use your own brand of language and be dismissive of others, I don't see how anyone can have a constructive discussion with you.

Comment: Note that since the new post notices were implemented, they refer to deleted posts as "hidden (e.g., "This post is hidden.").

Answer (score 8):

> Having your post deleted is very demoralizing

And so are downvotes. And people telling you that you're wrong. We can't make everything to appear nice and cozy, sometimes people just have to adjust, as harsh as it might seem.

> It's also intuitively considered permanent

And it is, in vast majority of cases. Having deleted posts undeleted is extremely rare.

---

As for wording: changing "deleted'" to "hidden" will send wrong signal that it can be easily be visible again, while it's not: after a post on Stack Exchange is deleted by moderator or high rep users, its author can't undelete it anymore, only another moderator or high rep users.

Comment: *"We can't make everything to appear nice and cozy, sometimes people just have to adjust".* You're saying we can't change it, but this isn't a reason in itself. What's bad about the suggestion would be reasons. *"Having deleted posts undeleted is extremely rare."*. This is tautology. It's basically saying that we can't make deleted posts more likely to be undeleted because undeleted posts are extremely rare.

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph, posts *can* be undeleted. They can be undeleted almost just as easily as writing an answer that won't be deleted in the first place. The only real difference is "awaiting moderator approval", which is a common message on the internet. I greatly disagree that "hidden" is less intuitive than deleted. Further, "any other word" is a big claim. There's lots of words, and sometimes they work even better if you choose two or three instead of just one. I don't think youcan reasonably claim no other word can possibly be better, not without many examples.

Comment: Correct about any other word, edited. Will reply to other claims later..