# Hold publishing a WIP question until it is good, and/or for some time

Tags: feature-request, on-hold

Feature request: hold publishing a question until it is good, and/or for some time

I like to edit and save and read the final result, but I do that like 10 to 20 times for many minutes... while I edit, some people are already reading the non final question...

And no, I can’t hold myself when I think it is OK and good, but later I find out some important details were not good or wrong...

So, could we save it like in a hidden state, for a few hours or days, then it would auto publish after a timeout based on the last edit time?

BTW, highly ranked members could still read [WIP](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/WIP#Noun) questions.

Comment: Auto-publishing is bad, because you need to monitor your question right after posting, in case somebody asks for more information. *"cant hold myself, i just cant"* What?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "and no, i cant hold myself when i think it is ok and good, but later i find out some important details were not good or wrong...". Ppl thought i was joking? Thats sad..

Comment: Actions have consequences.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog delete is not clear. It shoukd be called hide, as i thought it would remove the question and perm delete it. May be this is another suggestion about that confusing option...

Comment: A [prior request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308857/change-the-word-delete-to-hidden) to do exactly that was declined.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog i think i know a still better suggestion then. It should be called "send to trash" as the described behaviour of real deletion in 60 days is very similar to a trash behavior. While delete is still confusing. I will create a new question to see if i can get some upvotes this time and be able to properly comment like other meta citizens :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393671/change-delete-button-name-to-trash

Comment: Related: *[Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info)* has many of the same features (currently on hold due to [the (so-called) artificial intelligence craze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT))

Answer (score 7):

I've occasionally written a question, posted it, and decided... it wasn't *just right*.

You just delete it, review it till you feel it's right, and undelete it. I've occasionally used this as a way to 'preserve' a post that needed a little more work, while something else got my attention.

A high rep user (10K+ on bigger sites, or 2K) *could* view it if they had the link.

While there's no 'formal' reminder, you could always set a alert on your favoured calendar application.