# Why is the vote down privilege at 100 reputation instead of 125?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, privileges

Meta Stack Exchange has the [voting down privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) awarded at 100 reputation, rather than 125 reputation like the rest of the network. Other meta sites also require 125 reputation. Why does it take 25 less reputation to downvote here than the rest of the network?

Comment: Say there's a discussion on meta.SE that affects the site you have 10k rep in and care for. If you disagree with the premise of the discussion or the feature being proposed, how will you express your disagreement?

Comment: Why so much downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posts here can affect the entire network. Plus, if you have the association bonus you should be able to know how downvoting works and not be likely to abuse it.

Here is the reasoning from [the original FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273000/323179):

> This is to be expected for regular Stack Exchange sites as you are expected to be involved in the community before you are deemed knowledgeable enough to be part of the community voice. However, MSE is different because you are voting for the entirety of the Stack Exchange network and you shouldn't need to be active on MSE itself to have a voice on changes to the entire network.
>
> This is especially important for questions like [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956) because it will effect every network to do with coding at all. This was brought up in [this highly upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272965).