# Why is it that the new pronouns FAQ was relatively well received with a positive score, but the post for clarifications about it has a negative score?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta, code-of-conduct, meta-faq

As of November 23, 2019, [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/372935) has a (217 − 132 =) +85  score and [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/372935) has a (267 − 599 =) −332 score.

I haven't voted on any of the posts but I think the answers given by SO employees in the clarifications post improve upon the FAQ and if I vote my vote would be the same for both posts.

I don't understand why would anybody upvote the former and downvote the latter, and I'm looking for feedback from people who voted this way. A speculative explanation is also welcome.

Comment: To the close voter: how exactly "feedback from people who voted this way" is opinion based??? A speculative explanation is secondary not primary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it invites: 182+85 answers for the first question and 203+276 answers for the 2nd one. While there is likely to be overlap, and the ability to scroll through ***all*** the answers and upvote one instead of writing a new one, as we approach a few pages of answers that becomes less likely - and simply becomes a forum for people to express their memory of how/why they voted. --- Too broad an answer, it you don't like it being "opinion based".

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your explanation. However I strongly disagree. People who voted differently (if they even exist, read this question and decide to answer it) will probably have similar reasons, best case scenario there will be 2-3 answers. This question doesn't invite answers based on sound reasoning anymore than any other question, so far in the 2 hours it was opened there was only one answer by Glorfindel. I don't think your concern about having several pages of answers is realistic.

Comment: Oleg, that text was from the Review Queue; a custom close reason (agreed with by one other person), the other close reason was for (as you noted) "opinion based". `"... best case scenario there will be 2-3 answers."` that seems optimistic, the second question you linked to has **56** answers (spanning 1 1/4 pages, along with all the comments).  I said "a few pages" not several, careful reading and respect for others is what could have avoided all this in the first place. On a similar note you mention @Glorfindel, the ***first*** sentence says he didn't vote on either question, so that's more.

Comment: It could be for many reasons, but we can't answer without any data about the voters. One interesting point is that the locked post can't be voted upon any more. If someone can share the vote-history of No Opposition Allowed... uh.. i mean [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq?noredirect=1&lq=1), perhaps we could get an insight on what would happen.

Comment: Another interesting point is that the FAQ_2 post disallows any criticism. Imagine if people would read strong counter arguments to the pronoun CoC. Downvotes would skyrocket like they did the now deleted [FAQ_1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Some observations: (I haven't voted on either question):

- The [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/295232) is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) across the network, and [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/295232) is not.
- The feedback post is viewed about three times as often as the FAQ itself.
- [Users with the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286150/223820) no longer have to earn rep before they can downvote.
- Both have about the same number of upvotes (182 for the FAQ, 203 for the feedback post), the real difference is in the downvotes (-85 vs. -276).

Based on this, I *suspect* a lot of relatively uninformed users are only visiting the feedback post, downvote it because they're fed up with the topic and/or don't approve the changes (which is their right to do so), and don't bother to visit the FAQ which they'd otherwise downvote too.
If that is true, you won't find much people who voted the way you describe and they can't give you feedback :)

Comment: Could also be that people liked the FAQ at a first glance but didn't like the clarifications made in the feedback post?

Comment: Sure, but it's very hard to judge people's intentions and I'm not good at it. I prefer numbers, they're easier to work with :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you, it's definitely better this way. I only paid attention to the factual correctness of that sentence (it was edited in by another user).

Answer (score 10):

Much of the discrepancy may relate to the way the posting is structured.  There is the official publication, and a clear directive that all feedback should be on the dedicated feedback post.  The feedback post is just a bulletin board for any opinions or suggestions people have; logically, you can't really agree or disagree with a blank space.  The voting there is where many people are providing their feedback as to their opinion of the official publication.

There may also be some mixed thoughts about voting on the publication post.  It is much improved over the original, and the company largely listened to the advice of the community in revising it.  So while it still has issues, people want to recognize the company's effort to move in the right direction.  You get more of the behavior you want by rewarding good behavior and penalizing bad behavior.  Downvoting there is inconsistent with that strategy.

The feedback post is where people are actually responding to the content, so voting there can seem more like the best place to express dissatisfaction.