# Possible CSRF attack that cause answers to be added to "Top Answers" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, security, csrf

In Careers, adding answers to the "Top Answers" section of the profile is done via a pure GET request, e.g. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/stack/add-answer/45190?answerId=227366&site=meta

If I click the above link while logged in to Careers, [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227366/152859) is being added to my [public Careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/yahavbr). No confirmation, can only remove manually by editing.

Another example, if [Mr. Alien](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/205030/mr-alien) will click [this link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/stack/add-answer/131376?answerId=227476&site=meta) while logged in to Careers, it will cause [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227476/152859) to be added to his profile.

Can this please be fixed? (e.g. changing to POST, or requiring confirmation)

*(Since the impact is not critical and can be easily undone, I think it's proper to post it here)*

Comment: +1 Nice find..or bad find. I'm surprised such a basic security issue is present on a part of the Stack network. I mean no disrespect to Stack, in fact the quite opposite given the fact I am surprised.

Comment: @James well, the Careers team is **big**. Bigger team means bigger risk for mistakes.

Comment: Seriously, who downvoted this :rolleyes:

Comment: @James not me. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good catch! I've just pushed a fix for this. We now use a POST request (with a CSRF token) to add answers to your profile. If you try a GET request you'll now get a 404 error.