# Winter bash 2015 : People crazy about hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, secret-hats

I saw Users get crazy to wear different hats.

But I really think is this worth anything. There will be no value of your hat after some days. Your hats will be taken off forcefully. Really big reason to worry why we spent lot of time in earning hats.

Some bizarre effect of it. Getting hat users are removing their comments and answers; that might be useful for some one.

Just think on it. Is it worth? Why don't you go out and purchase one hat and wear it. That will be with you.

Comment: Is there a question in this post?

Comment: yes my question is. `Is it worth?`

Comment: You're asking if participating in an online game is worth the fun some people experience when participating in said game? (I'm pretty sure everyone playing the game realizes that you can't exchange hats for [unicoins](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins) or any other currency. They're participating because it's fun for them.)

Comment: @ff524 but in that at-least you can show your score to others. but in this one day surprisingly  all hat will be taken off from you head.

Comment: It's a cruel world we live in.

Comment: I'm tempted to post a question asking if it's worth asking a question about worthless activities. Just think on it :)

Comment: The Winterbash is temporary, and it was intended to be. Your post does essentially suggest not to participate it for this reason.

Comment: He says while wearing a hat.

Comment: Did you post this question hoping it will gain you some hat?

Comment: @Eran no . Nothing like that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a **HAT MANIAC**, and one of the top  users on the leaderboard, I want to comment on this:

### Hats are fun!

---

Simply because I collected a lot of hats doesn't mean I've broken site rules, it just means I've worked hard on them.

You listed the Cleanup Crew hat as an example: I got it on CodeReview.SE.

Over there, we comment to help users make their posts on-topic, or to improve the clarity of what they're doing, often those '*welcoming*' comments are rectified but sit absent on questions.

So when I went throughy my old comments, besides deleting my now obsolete comments, I managed to use up all of my comment flags flagging related comments.

> *Getting hat users are removing their answers*

I'd really wanna hope not. There's no hat for removing answers, and for good reason.

---

> *I saw peoples get crazy to wear different hats*

People may be crazy, but for the most part, that has a positive effect.

You have users trying to cap, and using their votes, *positively affecting* the community.

I don't know whether you've experienced this or not, but I find what you're talking about similar to cheating in video games.

While it's easy to type `givemeatank` and to get everything instantly, actually working for the ranks, the rewards (*hats*) is the real fun. (*Although getting and showing off the hats is fun too*).

> *Why dont you go out and purchase one hat and wear it. That will be with you.*

Buying a hat would be similar to cheating, while you have to work to pay for it, [earning it for doing good and trying hard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaabB.png) is much more rewarding.