# "An error occurred submitting the answer." when I tried to answer my own question

Tags: support, answers, 418-teapot-error

I had a question on the *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site:

*[Zorin OS boots into emergency mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574399/zorin-os-boots-into-emergency-mode)*

I was able to find out the problem after some time and decided to answer my own question. Here is the answer that I attempted to post:

[image]

It is a pretty plain answer and I can't figure out why it is not being accepted/posted. I checked many similar questions on the meta site, but none of them could help me solve my problem.

Comment: No  error messages in the console of your browser?

Comment: @rene It shows a 418: No reason phrase error

Comment: Try disabling all your browser extensions.

Comment: [418 Teapot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot)

Comment: @Laurel Thank you! Grammarly was the culprit here. I disabled it and was able to post the answer after that without any problems.

Comment: 418 is the error code used to represent a CSRF violation. It appears that Grammarly was interfering with the page in such a way that resulted in the system not passing the CSRF checks.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog oh I see, thanks for the info!