# Review submission missing POST data when opting to leave a question closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, error-message, 418-teapot-error

### Update 17:57Z

The issue appears to have been resolved. The POST data is sent with two keys: *fkey* and *closeReasonId*.

---

I'm attempting to review an item in the Code Review SE reopen queue. After opting to leave the post closed, I select a reason and then click the button labeled *Keep Closed* an error notification is displayed at the top of the screen. In the console, I see the request received a [418 response](https://http.cat/418). Can the response be a 2xx response soon, please?

[image: review queue response attempt]

This is occurring in Win10 & Mac OS 11.6 FF 93.0 64-bit, as well as Brave Version 1.22.71 Chromium: 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64), plus Safari 15.0 (16612.1.29.41.4, 16612), Chrome on iOS (with wifi disabled), MS Edge 94.0.992.50 (Official build) (64-bit) and Opera 80.0.4170.40 (x86_64).

It also happens in the Stack Overflow reopen queue.

After inspecting the POST request, it appears no POST data is getting submitted when opting to leave a question closed. When opting to reopen a question, the POST data contains 5 fields: *taskTypeId*, *taskResultTypeId*, *fkey*, *postCommentId*, and *taskResultSubtypeFlags*.

[image: no post data]

Comment: Disable all browser extensions (or [Grammarly, if you have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345425/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer-when-i-tried-to-answer-my-own-questio#comment1157311_345425)) and try again?

Comment: I tried in private mode in Brave (Chromium) so no extensions are loaded, as well as Safari and Chrome on iOS (with wifi disabled), which have no extensions installed - the issue persists there as well.

Comment: Happening for me, too, in the Stack Overflow Reopen queue (Windows 10, Edge). Disabling all user-scripts doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for reporting - I'm looking into it right now. Will keep y'all updated.

Comment: Not sure when it started. Things were fine, yesterday, and others seem to have been able to [review today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats).

Comment: @AdrianMole - I mean, _Your Majesty_ - perhaps the users have been able to review today as long as they opted to reopen, which appears to not be missing POST data.

Comment: @kristinalustig after reloading it appears to send the POST data now.

Comment: FWIW this did help us find a different but somewhat related bug that existed with inbox notifications for posts that get left closed in the Reopen Queue so double thanks for reporting this issue!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Glad to hear the fix worked! It was a "`this` is weird" issue.