# Why does the boardgames Stack Exchange site think it's a teapot?

Tags: support, status-norepro, error-message

I'm trying to post something to the *[Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, and it looks like the server is returning [HTTP code 418, I'm a Teapot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418):

[image: Console with HTTP codes of 418 I'm a teapot]

What's going on?

This is the content of my post:

```
Occasionally, a deck becomes famous which is a [colour combination][1] + a 'splash' of another colour.

One good example is 'Moist Jund', which is Jund (Black, Red and Green) plus a small amount of blue (which gives the Moist part of the name).

What are the names of the other splashes? That is, splashing for White, Black, Green and Red.
```

The only tag was [magic-the-gathering](/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering).

When I go into the developer tools, and look at the preview to a response, I get this:

[image: Suspicious request error page]

Comment: That is an error code that we use when a request is malformed in a specific way. Can you please include more information about what you were trying to do?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I've added in the post conent

Comment: You received this when you were trying to post the question, and you can repro this at will?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I haven't navigated away from the page, and my dev tools is still open. I can press submit again now and see if it works, but I didn't want to lose any debug information by refreshing

Comment: Try again in a new window

Comment: Background: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot

Comment: @Luuklag It's working now

Comment: What browser? Google Chrome?

Comment: @p.mort yeah Google Chrome

Comment: BTW you can access the "418 : I am a Teapot" error page from [here](https://www.google.com/teapot)