# Suspicious Request

Tags: support

When I try to login to stackoveflow via Facebook for the first time, I see the following error:

> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again.

[image]

This question has sort of been asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170875/241252), but this answers the cause, and doesn't provide the solution. What can I do to prevent this situation? Changing my ISP isn't an option.

Edit: SSHing into a remote server sort of solved this problem. But I need a more permanent solution.

Comment: @OGHaza I know that. But that answer doesn't provide the solution. It just brings out the cause as I said. Plus, I've provided the above link in the question itself.

Comment: Of course changing your ISP is an option. So is moving to a different county, province, city, state, country, continent, planet...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I need a solution that is the most efficient and uses the minimum amount of resources. And who can guarantee that things work when I change my ISP?

Comment: I still think it's a dupe. What more than Balpha's answer do you expect? Also, if there's a better answer, then such should be posted to the duplicate as well, I feel.