# Can't get into chat

Tags: support, chat, login

I am logged in to Stack Overflow. But when I try to enter a chat room, there is an error message:

> First, log in to your account.

What is the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to troubleshoot using http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Long shot: maybe your IP address is changing rapidly. Can you verify this by clicking Start --> Run --> cmd --> ipconfig and see what's your IP, then repeat it every minute or so, to see if it's really changing? In such case, it cause problems with login. (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170923/152859))